# SetState creating duplicate entries

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to generate an array of UI controls as they're being rendered and the resulting state contains duplicate entries. Is there a good way to protect against this?

This code is fired each time a component is rendered. There are multiple tables with similar controls and I'm using this to get the maximum number of rows per control:

```
        const newcontrols: LoadedCtrls = {
            "itemCtrlType": controlType,
            "rowsCount": numberRows,
        };
        if (this.state.loadedcontrols.length == 0) {
            this.setState({
                loadedcontrols: [...this.state.loadedcontrols, newcontrols]
            })
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.loadedcontrols.length; i++) {
            if (this.state.loadedcontrols[i].itemCtrlType == controlType) {
                if (this.state.loadedcontrols[i].rowsCount < numberRows) {
                    this.setState({
                        loadedcontrols: [...this.state.loadedcontrols.slice(0, i), newcontrols, ...this.state.loadedcontrols.slice(i)]
                    })
                }
            }
            else {
                this.setState({
                    loadedcontrols: [...this.state.loadedcontrols, newcontrols]
                })
            }
        }
```

The result in the console is the following:

```
[{"itemCtrlType":"map1","rowsCount":2},{"itemCtrlType":"map2","rowsCount":3},{"itemCtrlType":"location","rowsCount":5},{"itemCtrlType":"map2","rowsCount":3},{"itemCtrlType":"monitor","rowsCount":7},{"itemCtrlType":"monitor","rowsCount":7}]
```

I've attempted to use good practices with immutability but it still seems like setState is firing off with duplicates, and I know it is an asynchronous operation. So is there a way to prevent this?

EDIT: The function is triggered each time a component's fetch function outputs data, and the state is set in the component:

```
            .then(data => {
            this.setState({
                results: data,
                loading: false,
            }, () => {
                this.finishLoad(this.state.controlType, this.state.customerId, data.length);
            });
        });
```

Comment: How is the code "fired each time a component is rendered"?

Comment: See the new edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `setState()` can lead to very uncertain behavior; for two reasons:

1. `setState()` should not be used as a synchronous call (i.e., you rely on `state` being updated immediately).
2. Calling `setState()` as you are iterating over the state may not have the intended behavior (because of 1.).

You might consider a more general pattern:

```
let localState=this.state;
   // Rely on and modify localState, as desired
this.setState(localState) // Set final state and trigger potential re-render
```

You may not need to specify the callback in your initial `setState()` call since state changes are batched and the next render is implicitly invoked.

The following read *may* be helpful [setState() State Mutation Operation May Be Synchronous In ReactJS](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2893-setstate-state-mutation-operation-may-be-synchronous-in-reactjs.htm)